Post request in Strapi
How do I submit a "Post" request using axios in Strapi with a authorization token ? I have trying everything but I fail .
Sorry for my bad English ( Isn't my native langauges ) . I expect to at least have some info about problem

Its really simple and well defined in the Strapi docs.

ref : https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest
If you are not clear about the authorization token. It needs to be in Authorization header in Api request  Here is the sample Strapi post Api from Postman :

Here comes the Authorization Token

